# How to attach an AWS Instance profile to an Existing Amazon EC2 Instance dynamically to connect to secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-secrets-manager

I have kitchen.yaml it creates ec2 instance dynamically ,when ever kitchen.yaml launches new instance I need to connect to secrets manager using instance profile,
but I have to attach instance profile using chef recipe
can anyone please suggest me how do I achieve this.

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: In the subject you mention *IAM Role*, in the body you talk about *instance profile*. Those are two very different things. You may need to reword your question to clarify. Either way, the fact that you can't login to instance manually seems irrelevant

Comment: Also it is a good idea to show the code you have written so far. In particular `kitchen.yaml` or any Chef recipe that you are running.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean by "kitchen.yaml", and whether you use *lunches* instance (instead of *launches*) as pun - but quick google search gives the best [result](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-iam-instance-profile.html):

```
aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile
        --iam-instance-profile <value>
        --instance-id <value>
```

Obviously, you need to get the id of the instance that got launched (it's *launched*; not *created*)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I can't login to instance manually so I have to attach through chef recipe any ideas, thanks

Comment: my answer does not require you to login to instance. You run it from command line *outside* the instance through AWS CLI. Are you familiar with AWS CLI?